# How can we put data on particular row index on GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview which binds some data from database except Quantity Textbox. There is also  a button on Grid on each click of this button one number is added to the quantity box (This I want to show on grid). Please see my code below & suggest me.

**Code :**

```
if (e.CommandName == "Next")
   {
       int Index_Next = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
       TextBox Quantity = (TextBox)grdSale.Rows[Index_Next].FindControl(&quot;txtDisplay&quot;);
       int Val_Next = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity.Text);
       if (Val_Next != 0 &amp;&amp; Val_Next &gt; 1)
       {
           Val_Next = Val_Next + 1;
       }
       (TextBox)grdSale.Rows[Index_Next].FindControl(&quot;txtDisplay&quot;) = Val_Next.ToString();    // Here I'm getting error. I also convert this string to TextBox but still show error.
   }
```

Comment: "Here I'm getting error" Always post the exact error message.

Comment: @Tim.. I'll take care in future.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

but you are assigning  to `TextBox`

```
(TextBox)grdSale.Rows[Index_Next]
                .FindControl("txtDisplay") = Val_Next.ToString();
```

which is wrong in first place, as Left side is `System.Web.UI.WebContols.TextBox` and right side is `String` . You should try and set the Text of Found `TextBox`. You should be doing

```
((TextBox)grdSale.Rows[Index_Next]
                 .FindControl("txtDisplay")).Text = Val_Next.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (e.CommandName == "Next")
    {
        int Index_Next = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        TextBox Quantity = (TextBox)grdSale.Rows[Index_Next].FindControl("txtDisplay");
        int Val_Next = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity.Text);
        if (Val_Next != 0 && Val_Next < 1)
        {
            Val_Next = Val_Next + 1;
        }
        ((TextBox)grdSale.Rows[Index_Next].FindControl("txtDisplay")).Text = Val_Next.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: how does your answer makes difference?